# vertica/sqlalchemy - Permission denied for schema public

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, vertica

I am able to generate an engine as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
url = sa.url.URL(drivername='vertica+pyodbc',
    username='username',
    password='****',
    host='vertica')
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
```

I can read data, e.g.

```
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_schema.tablename", engine)
```

However when I try to write data:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))
df.to_sql("my_schema.random_table", engine)
```

I get the error

Permission denied for schema public\n (4367) (SQLExecDirectW)') u'\nCREATE TABLE "my_schema.random_table"

I believe that the issue is that "my_schema.random_table" is being wrapped by quotes, making Vertica think I want to create this table in the base (public) schema instead of my_schema. Is there a way I can specify the schema I want in the ODBC url?

Comment: You can try setting the search path to the schema (`SET SEARCH_PATH TO my_schema;`), then executing the `CREATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) has a `schema` parameter.  Try using that instead of specifying the schema as a prefix to the table name.

```
df.to_sql('random_table', engine, schema='my_schema')
```